# Characteristic time or time constant for diffusion (heat) equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, partial-derivative, heat-equation

Is there a time constant or a characteristic time it takes for the diffusion equation

$$\frac{\partial \psi(\vec{x}, t)}{\partial t} = D \nabla^2 \psi(\vec{x},t)+V(\vec{x})$$

to reach steady-state conditions? You can assume the inhomogenous term $V(\vec{x})$ is time-independent, and that the problem is well-posed, and so on.

Comment: What about $\delta^2/D$, where $\delta$ is some characteristic length of your problem?

Comment: That would clearly be correct just from dimensional analysis, but how would I find this characteristic length? In the problem posed above, the medium is continuous.

Comment: What's your domain? Do you have any boundary conditions?

Comment: On a bounded domain it is around $d^2/D$ for $d$ the diameter of the domain. On an unbounded domain it depends strongly on $V$; in the case $V=0$ the lowest Fourier modes relax arbitrarily slowly so there is not really a characteristic time for the whole system. But if $V$ has a negative integral over the whole space then the low modes can relax faster (on the other hand in this case there is no mass conservation, so this is likely not desired in any application).

Comment: Ian, would you mind being more mathematically precise on your discussion of the Fourier modes? I'm having a little trouble understanding. I know how to take the Fourier transform of the diffusion equation but what do you mean / how do you define "relaxation of the Fourier modes"? Thank you in advance.

Comment: So #1 I made an error: for decay of the low frequency Fourier modes you want $V$ to have an integral of the opposite sign of the integral of $\psi$. Anyway, what I said is just referring to the ODEs in the frequency domain $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \hat{\psi}(t,\xi)=-D |\xi|^2 \hat{\psi}(t,\xi) + \hat{V}(\xi)$. For arbitrarily small $\xi$ that first term yields arbitrarily slow decay, but $\hat{V}(\xi)$ can potentially accelerate things (or slow them down) depending on signs.